# How to append querystrings to a URL on submit of a form?

Tags: html, forms, mailchimp

Ok, so I have 2 forms on a clients website (website is built in wordpress).

The client is using Mail Chimp for his email marketing and has 2 forms set up in Mail Chimp to capture users data and subscribe them to two different lists.

I have 2 sections on the website with mini versions of these forms - The forms he has done in mail chimp are much bigger and require allot more details the ones I have on the site only have name, phone, email.

I have read an article on mail chimps blog that talks about how you can auto fill certain fields on the form on page load by adding the relevant query to the end of the url e.g. ***http:/FORMADRESS&MERGE1=Jack*** - this would pre-fill the "First Name" box on the form with the name Jack.

(([http://blog.mailchimp.com/how-to-pre-fill-items-on-your-mailchimp-hosted-form](http://blog.mailchimp.com/how-to-pre-fill-items-on-your-mailchimp-hosted-form/)/))

How can I add these query strings to the end of the URL in order to prefil the 3 fields from the mini form on the site on the large mail chimp form?

Any alternative solutions anyone is aware of would also be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 15):

A form should do the trick, if I understand you correctly:

```
<form action="http://echo.iambroken.com/" method="get">
    <input name="one">
    <input name="two">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Note that if there’s already a query string on the `action` URL, this will replace it — so if there are other parameters on the URL already, include them instead in the form as hidden inputs like this one:

```
<input type="hidden" name="q" value="123">
```

Comment: Thanks Very much! I'll give this a go later. Cheers for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can append a hidden variable to form using simply append query
Here you can do as following in your javacript.

```
Var hiddenVar="<input type="hidden" name="q" value="123">"
$('form').append(hiddenVar)
```

and you can get this value request parameter on your action.

Answer (score 1):

Using JQuery you can modify the action attribute when the form loads. In the example below I am filtering out just the QueryString parameters I need submitted with the form and applying them to the action.

```
$(function(){
    var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
    var id = urlParams.get('id');
    var codeid = urlParams.get('codeid');
    var params = "?id=" + id + "&codeid=" + codeid;
    $("form").attr("action", location.pathname + params);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You get mini form three fields and push them to other form as hidden fields. Then when used submit them, hidden field also part of the form and will be added to URL.

Comment: Could you expand on that a bit? I'm not exactly an expert - more a graphic designer than a web designer so any advice on how would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: You can get mini form values and push them to main form using javascript, then in the main form you get values from mini form to hidden fields. If you can share your form to Fiddle we'll try to go for example.